# Magmi Image path not found

Tags: magento-1.9, php, import, csv, magmi

I am uploading 1000 products to Magento 1.9 using Magmi's Image Attributes Processor and receive the following error

> SKU 3800231 - Image attributes processor v1.0.33 - path/853698004078.jpg cannot be found in images path
>   my file structure as follow

```
Shop/MagentoRoot/Magmi/
                /var/import/xxxxx.csv
                /media/import/xxxxxxx.jpg
```

I have tried the following as my path in my .csv

```
/xxxx.jpg
xxxx.jpg
/media/import/xxx.jpg
/shop/MagentoRoot/media/import/xxx.jpg
/home/ShareServerPath/public_html/shop/MagentoRoot/media/import/xxx.jpg
```

what is the right path? or how do i debug it to find the right path

thank you